# Entity Framework Core using Multiple Contexts with different connection strings in the same Transaction

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Using EF Core it is recommended to use transactions with the following:

```
using (var dbContextTransaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction())
{

}
```

How does one use a transaction that can span multiple contexts which also have different connection strings i.e. we cannot use SqlConnection.BeginTransation as the 2 contexts have different connection strings.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `TransactionScope` objects when you need a transaction which have a bigger scope than the context you are using. This requires Entity Framework Core 2.1, as described on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/transactions:

> ## Using System.Transactions
>
> **Note**: This feature is new in EF Core 2.1.
>
> It is possible to use ambient transactions if you need to coordinate across a larger scope.

So use something like this:

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope()) {
    // create and work with context here
}
```